# XSLT to remove namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML code:

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <GetBillList xmlns="old_uri">
     <Case>
        <CaseID>699677</CaseID>
        <BillGroup>
           <BillGroupID>1</BillGroupID>
        </BillGroup>
     </Case>
     <StartDate>2014-06-12</StartDate>
     <GetBillListResponse>
        <Case>
           <CaseID>699677</CaseID>
           <BillGroup>
              <BillGroupID>1</BillGroupID>
              <Bill>
                 <BillNumber>380368215926</BillNumber>
                 <BillTypeAbbreviation>List Bill</BillTypeAbbreviation>
                    <BillPaymentStatusCode>
                    <BillPaymentStatusCode>UNPAID</BillPaymentStatusCode>
                    <tc>2</tc> 
                     </BillPaymentStatusCode>
                 <BillCycleCode>
                    <BillCycleCode>Monthly Bill Cycle</BillCycleCode>
                    <tc>MTHL</tc>
                 </BillCycleCode>                 
                 <PaymentErrorCode/>
                 <FromDate>2014-12-01</FromDate>
                </Bill>
               </BillGroup>
        </Case>
     </GetBillListResponse>
  </GetBillList>
  </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried this XSL code:

```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ouaf="old_uri" exclude-result-prefixes="ouaf">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="2.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ouaf:GetBillList/ouaf:GetBillListResponse"/>
  </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[ouaf:tc]">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:for-each select="ouaf:tc">
<xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::ouaf:tc)]"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ouaf:*">
 <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="new_uri">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[name(.) = name(..)]">
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And got this output:

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
    <GetBillListResponse xmlns="new_uri">
        <Case>
            <CaseID>699677</CaseID>
            <BillGroup>
                <BillGroupID>1</BillGroupID>
                <Bill>
                    <BillNumber>380368215926</BillNumber>
                    <BillTypeAbbreviation>List Bill</BillTypeAbbreviation>
                    <BillPaymentStatusCode xmlns="old_uri" tc="2">UNPAID</BillPaymentStatusCode>
                    <BillCycleCode xmlns="old_uri" tc="MTHL">Monthly Bill Cycle</BillCycleCode>
                    <PaymentErrorCode/>
                    <FromDate>2014-12-01</FromDate>
                </Bill>
            </BillGroup>
        </Case>
    </GetBillListResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Required Output:

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
    <GetBillListResponse xmlns="new_uri">
        <Case>
            <CaseID>699677</CaseID>
            <BillGroup>
                <BillGroupID>1</BillGroupID>
                <Bill>
                    <BillNumber>380368215926</BillNumber>
                    <BillTypeAbbreviation>List Bill</BillTypeAbbreviation>
                    <BillPaymentStatusCode tc="2">UNPAID</BillPaymentStatusCode>
                    <BillCycleCode tc="MTHL">Monthly Bill Cycle</BillCycleCode>
                    <PaymentErrorCode/>
                    <FromDate>2014-12-01</FromDate>
                </Bill>
            </BillGroup>
        </Case>
    </GetBillListResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Everything is fine except the old_uri namespace which is coming in those elements which have tc as an attribute. I want to remove that namespace from my output XML.
Would appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you match the element with `tc` as a child, you start off by simply copying it:

But the element you are copying is in the old namespace, and so the copied element will be in the old namespace too.

Instead of copying the element, you can create a new one, with `xsl:element`, specifying the new namespace

```
<xsl:template match="*[ouaf:tc]">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="new_uri">
    <xsl:for-each select="ouaf:tc">
      <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::ouaf:tc)]"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: But still I am getting Namespaces. I dont want namespaces where tc attribute is there. Only new_uri will be there in the root node.

Comment: Please make it clear what output you are now getting and how it differs from the required output.

Comment: I have tested my answer at http://xsltransform.net/bdxtqC and it seems to match what you expect.